# Plot two figures on the same figure using subplot

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to plot the following using `subplot` how can I do that? Thank you

```
[n,wc]= buttord(Wp,Ws,Rp,Rs);  
[z,p,k]=butter(n,wc);
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);   


freqz(sos) ;
grpdelay(sos) ;
```

Note that this is non-trivial since [`freqz`](http://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html#bt8l89o-1) yields a subplot already.

Comment: You should have been more elaborate with your question, without [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374467/plot-two-figures-on-the-same-figure-using-subplot#comment43200085_27374898) clarifying on [`freqz`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html#bt8l89o-1) creating a subplot this question seemed trivial.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - I agree that this is no longer a duplicate.  I will vote to reopen.  The OP should have explicitly stated that `subplot` did not work out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following **would work** if the functions you are using plotted one figure each: call `subplot` right before each function that produces a graphic output. It is kind of straightforward from the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html), `subplot(m,n,p)` splits the figure into a grid of m x n graphics and draws the p-th one. However, as pointed by @hbaderts, `freqz` produces a subplot of its own, so you would need to rearrange it to include the upcoming output of `grpdelay`.

This is how you could do it, as per the workaround proposed in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/136971) thread (see it for the more *general* solution).

```
freqz(sos);
h = get(gcf, 'children');
fig2=figure;
figure(fig2)
g=subplot(3,1,1)
set(h(1), 'pos', get(g, 'pos'))
figure(fig2)
g=subplot(3,1,2)
set(h(2), 'pos', get(g, 'pos'))
close
g=subplot(3,1,3)
grpdelay(sos)
```

Comment: As `freqz` plots magnitude and phase in subplots, this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest solution is calculating the frequency response with `freqz` and plotting it with `freqzplot`. This is not the best solution because `freqzplot` is obsolete. A better solution would be to manually create the plots (e.g. `20*log10(abs(h))`).

```
[h,w] = freqz(sos);
subplot(2,2,1);
freqzplot(h,w,'mag');
subplot(2,2,3);
freqzplot(h,w,'phase');
subplot(2,2,[2,4]);
grpdelay(sos);
```